# Tolerated use of the term topology

Tags: graphs, terminology, data-structures, trees

In the field of data structures (and maybe in graph theory), can we use the term topology to speak about the shape of a tree? For instance, consider the two following trees :

1) The first one:
Node $a$ is parent of $b$ and $c$.
Node $e$ is parent of $a$ and $d$

2) the second one:
Node $a$ is parent of nodes $b$, $c$ and $d$.

Can we say that their topology are different, in the sense that the set of relations parents/children are different?

Comment: It's a use of a technical term in a less than formal way, but only a serious pedant would take you to task if you said that two graph-like structures had different topologies. I've seen the term frequently (and, IMO, acceptably) to describe network structures, for example.

Comment: I believe that this is common usage.

Comment: If you want, you can actually relate this informal usage to the mathematical notion of topology on finite sets, e.g. by considering the Alexandrov topology (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) on your trees (for example, your second example would have open sets $\emptyset$ as well as all subsets containing $a$).

Comment: I'd use "shape".

Comment: Why do you insist on using "topology" there though? Couldn't you just say they are different trees? Or that they are (somehow) structurally different?

Comment: @Juho Thanks for your comment. Is the term structure (or shape) well defined ?

Comment: No, I don't think structure or shape have precise meaning. But I don't think topology does either. Isomorphism has, as suggested by @D.W. in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I suppose you could, though it might be viewed as a somewhat informal usage of the term "topology".  "Shape" would probably be a better word, as @Raphael suggests.

A more precise way would be to say that these two trees are not [isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism).

Background: Two graphs $G,G'$ are considered isomorphic if there exists a map $f:V \to V'$ that is a [graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism).  Since any tree can be viewed as a graph, you can consider two trees to be isomorphic if they are isomorphic as graphs.  One can also define a natural notion of a tree isomorphism directly; this happens to be equivalent to the notion of a graph isomorphism for unrooted trees, but is slightly different (and more appropriate to use) for rooted trees.  You can read more about isomorphisms in standard sources.

Comment: How can we be assured that two trees are not isomorphic ? Maybe the trees I have are isomorphic, while having a different shape ?

Comment: @user7060, well, you write a mathematical proof that they are not isomorphic.  That proof refers back to the definition of isomorphism.  The appropriate proof techniques will differ.  Sometimes it's as simple as saying "G has a node of degree 7, G' doesn't", sometimes it can be much more complex to prove it -- but in any case, the way you can be assured is to prove the statement.